# Извлечение иконок

Tags: c#, winforms

Привет всем! Как из .exe (выбор через OpenFileDialog) файла получить его иконку и поместить её в PictureBox, и чтобы можно было с PictureBoxсохранить её через SaveFileDialog.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно попробывать так:
Так получем список ресурсов:

```
Assembly.LoadFile("name.exe").GetManifestResourceNames();
```

а грузим так:

```
pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(
  Assembly.LoadFile("name.exe").GetManifestResourceStream("name"),
  true);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогли